# How to insert into type text

Tags: sql

I wish to insert into an SQL table in a field whose data type is text.  However I am informed of an error saying ' check datatype' my Name field is of type nvarchar and my job field is of type text.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Job) VALUES ('John', 'Clerk')
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what is the **exact** error message you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS SQL Server, you wont be able to insert string values(with more than 1 characters) in table if the column of type nvarchar. You can only insert only one character using nvarchar.

If you wish to insert some text, please specify the some size with nvarchar.

For example in your case:

```
Create table Table1(Name nvarchar(5), Job Text)

Insert into Table1(Name, Job) values ('John','Clerk')
```

This will work.

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the insight